# How to send headers twice (100 continue)

Tags: php, symfony, http-status-code-100

I am trying to utilize `HTTP 100 continue` with `preload` headers to preload some content to browsers.
The issue is that I am not getting the expected result.
Here is my sample code:

```php
header('HTTP/1.1 100 Continue');
header('Link: </assets/style.css>; rel=preload');
header('Link: </assets/app.js>; rel=preload');
header(''); // send empty line to end 100 continue section
flush();

sleep (4); // Emulate some processing while browser is preloading assets

header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
echo "aaa\n";
echo "bbb\n";
flush();

exit;
```

But instead of expected response of:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
Link: </assets/style.css>; rel=preload
Link: </assets/app.js>; rel=preload

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

aaa
bbb
```

I am getting this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 04 Oct 2023 15:21:24 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.57 (Ubuntu)
Link: </assets/app.js>; rel=preload
Upgrade: h2,h2c
Connection: Upgrade
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

aaa
bbb
```

Am I missing something?
Do I need something more than just `flush()` to send the `100 continue` header?

My current stack is `apache` + `php-fpm`.
And command I use is `curl -i https://localhost/`

Also I will be using this with a symfony project so I need to make sure to reset `headers_sent()` after the `100 continue` section, or symfony will just not send anything (the send function starts with `if(headers_sent()) return;`),
But I am not sure how to reset it after the first flush.

Comment: You can only set one header of each type per HTTP response. Even if you use output buffering in PHP to periodically sent body content in stages, it's still technically only one HTTP request and response as far as the webserver and browser/client is concerned, I think

Comment: Although it does seem 100 is a bit of a special-case status, but at the very least as https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/100 mentioned, you'll need to be a bit more subtle on the client-side as well in order to make use of it. I still don't necessarily think it means you can send that status repeatedly though. More explanation at https://http.dev/100 - it's only supposed to be used _before_ the client transmits the request body, I think. You can't use it to tell a client to expect more response data.

Comment: P.S. I'm not aware of a need to use 100 Continue statuses when using preload headers. As I've shown, 100 has a different purpose. But you seem to have tied them together, it's not clear why you are attempting this? I would imagine you can just set the preload headers and get rid of the 100

Comment: @ADyson I based this solution on documentation of H2O's HTTP/2 preloads: https://h2o.examp1e.net/configure/http2_directives.html

Also HTTP specification states that `A client MUST be able to parse one or more 1xx responses received prior to a final response, even if the client does not expect one.  A user agent MAY ignore unexpected 1xx responses.`
so there should be no issue in using 100 responses.

The main reason why I want to use a separate 100 response is that some headers of the actual response (including the response code) need time to calculate and I want to send preload asap.

Comment: `I based this solution on documentation of H2O's HTTP/2 preloads`...but you're not using HTTP2 here. You're using HTTP 1.1, as shown from your log output. So yeah maybe the allowed usage is different in HTTP2 but it's irrelevant to your current setup

Comment: Also where is the output of the response you've shown us coming from? As per the HTTP spec also, if the client didn't sent the "expects" header before the 100, it's allowed to ignore the 100 response coming back

Comment: @ADyson *"You can only set one header of each type per HTTP response"* See the `$replace` parameter of [header()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

Answer (score 2):

Preloading just tells the browser ahead of time that some resources need to be fetched, which reduces load and possible render time of a page.

Usually your browser loads css/js/images/etc when they are read from the html, which happens parsed, line by line.
If your html is large, you can tell the browser to load some resources before the browser has seen them in the HTML (because it has seen them in the response headers).

You don't need to flush the content first, the headers are ALWAYS read before the html is read. As soon as the browser sees a preload, it starts pulling that file, even before the html is parsed.

The only thing you need to do is applying those headers, ahead of time. That's why most frameworks don't use `<?php echo "<html>" ?>` because now you can not send any headers anymore.
Html responses are deferred, so you know which resources are required for a page, so you can add those response headers.

Since you tagged `symfony`, it seems that a Controller has a method called `addLink`, which does this for you.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/web_link.html#resource-hints

Comment: This wont help, since Symfony will only send headers when all results are ready and calculated, which will take some time to do. That is why I wanted the `100 continue` response before the main one, so browser can start loading stuff, while backend is still calcularting the resutl.

Comment: That's not how response headers work and also how this Link header works.  What you are referring to is flushing your server buffer, but you can not change what you've already sent. You can not send multiple of the same headers, you have to combine them. Browsers also run an OPTIONS and/or a HEAD request, on which you can respond with other headers. You may try and add them there instead, but no guarantees. I couldn't find anything for that in the Link header specs.